# Convert const to class in React Native?

Tags: javascript, class, react-native

I have following functionality in React Native app

```
const GreenWood = ({x,y,z,f1,f2, f3}) => {
  ...
}
```

I need to convert it to class

```
class GreenWood extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
  ...
}
```

But my props x, y, x are undefined. How to propely forward them?

Comment: May I advise reading the following [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html), and [this possible related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops) and looking into mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: Well i read that guide, it describes "functional" way that I'm trying to move from, but not the one I need. Also, I'm not using Redux, just creating the component and want to forward some props. In other languages this usually done in constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a functional component `GreenWood` that returns some JSX.

```
class Greenwood extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   //...whatever construction you need
  }
  render() {
   const { x, y, z, f1, f2, f3 } = this.props
   return // your JSX Here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can destructure props on classes. You would have to add this.props in front of all those variables, or inside the method you are using it do:

`var { x, y, z, f1, f2, f3 } = this.props`

or just put the ones you are using inside that method.

Comment: can I do like this after super in the constructor? I tried to do this.x = props.x; but without success

Comment: You can do this.x = this.props.x, since you converted to class you have to put 'this' in front of props.