# When I convert component from stateless to statefull, data is not read in time;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs, react-redux, extreact

So first I had a stateless component, and the data is read fine and just in time, and then when, for my needs, I needed to convert it to a stateful component it is not working for some reason like it should. It leaves the data empty for that component. It doesn't even show the Wait... string. This is my current component:

```js
class ItemGroupComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userShortcutAreLoading: false,
            labelnameDefinition: [],
            labelnamesAreloading: false,
            itemGroupDefinition: [],
            itemGroupIsLoading: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            userShortcutAreLoading: this.props.userShortcutAreLoading,
            labelnameDefinition: this.props.labelnameDefinition,
            labelnamesAreloading: this.props.labelnamesAreloading,
            itemGroupDefinition: this.props.itemGroupDefinition,
            itemGroupIsLoading: this.props.itemGroupIsLoading
        })
    }

    loadData(e, item){
        console.log(e);
        console.log(item);

    }

    render(){

        if(this.state.labelnamesAreloading === true && this.state.itemGroupIsLoading === true){
            return (<h1> Wait... </h1>) //it doesn't even show the wait...
        }

        console.log("ITEM GROUP");
        console.log(this.state.itemGroupDefinition); //this is always empty
        return (
            <Button ui="button1" arrow={false} ripple={false} iconCls="icon-settings" border={false} >
                <Menu title={this.state.labelnameDefinition['settings.tab.title']} ui='headerMenu'>
                    {this.state.itemGroupDefinition.map((item) =>
                        <MenuItem key={item.id} iconCls={item.iconCls} text={item.name} ui="menuItem1" handler={() => this.loadData}/>
                    )}
                </Menu>
            </Button>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userShortcutAreLoading: state.coreuireducer.userShortcutAreLoading,
        labelnameDefinition: state.coreuireducer.labelnameDefinition,
        labelnamesAreloading: state.coreuireducer.labelnamesAreloading,
        itemGroupDefinition: state.coreuireducer.itemGroupDefinition,
        itemGroupIsLoading: state.coreuireducer.itemGroupIsLoading
    }
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(itemGroupAction, dispatch)
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (ItemGroupComponent);
```

-Part of the code which calls ItemGroupComponent:

```js
<NavItem className="d-md-down-none ">
    {/*Search menu*/}
    <NavLink href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Settings">{/*<i className="icon-settings"></i>*/}
      <ItemGroupComponent />
    </NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this `ItemGroupComponent`?

Comment: I have added it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `redux`, you don't use the normal `react` state pattern. Using `mapStateToProps` as you have (and assuming your reducer is valid and working) will map your `redux`-managed state (which you are maintaining in your reducer) to your component's `props`. So what you want is more like:

```
class ItemGroupComponent extends Component {

    loadData(e, item){
        console.log(e);
        console.log(item);

    }

    render(){
        const { // destructuring this.props, which now contains your state and is managed using redux
          userShortcutAreLoading,
          labelnameDefinition,
          labelnamesAreloading,
          itemGroupDefinition,
          itemGroupIsLoading
        } = this.props;
        if(labelnamesAreloading === true && itemGroupIsLoading === true){
            return (<h1> Wait... </h1>) //it doesn't even show the wait...
        }

        console.log("ITEM GROUP");
        console.log(itemGroupDefinition); //this is always empty
        return (
            <Button ui="button1" arrow={false} ripple={false} iconCls="icon-settings" border={false} >
                <Menu title={labelnameDefinition['settings.tab.title']} ui='headerMenu'>
                    {itemGroupDefinition.map((item) =>
                        <MenuItem key={item.id} iconCls={item.iconCls} text={item.name} ui="menuItem1" handler={() => this.loadData}/>
                    )}
                </Menu>
            </Button>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userShortcutAreLoading: state.coreuireducer.userShortcutAreLoading,
        labelnameDefinition: state.coreuireducer.labelnameDefinition,
        labelnamesAreloading: state.coreuireducer.labelnamesAreloading,
        itemGroupDefinition: state.coreuireducer.itemGroupDefinition,
        itemGroupIsLoading: state.coreuireducer.itemGroupIsLoading
    }
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(itemGroupAction, dispatch)
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (ItemGroupComponent);
```

You might want to read up a little more on `redux` since it looks like you have a misunderstanding of how it works or how to implement it. I think [this](https://learn.co/lessons/map-state-to-props-readme) looks like a decent tutorial, and the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow) are always a good place to start. Also see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops).

Comment: No problem at all ;-)