# How do i pull data from redux state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im trying to make an api request from redux then take that data and put it in my react state (arrdata). The api call works but i cant seem to get the state on my app.js to update based on the redux api call. Am i missing something?

#### App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arrdata: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadData();
    console.log(this.props.data);
  }
  render() {
     const {arrdata} = this.state
    return ( ......)}}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dataAction)(App);
```

#### Action

```
export function loadData() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get("https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets").then(response => {
      dispatch(getData(response.data.data.slice(0, 10)));
    });
  };
}

export function getData(data) {
  return {
    type: "GET_DATA",
    data: data
  };
}
```

#### Reducer

```
let initialState = {
  data: []
};

const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "GET_DATA") {
    return {
      ...state,
      data: action.data
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...state
    };
  }
};

export default mainReducer;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding React-Redux and mapStateToProps()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misleading store with state. Your `arrdata` is empty since it's stored inside state, but your data comes from props.

Anyways, `arrdata` in state remains empty, since you are not setting the state anywhere. To do that, you would have to use e.g. `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle hook, however I wouldn't recommend that.

```
render() {
   const { data } = this.props;
   console.log(this.props.data);

   return (
     // do something with your data
   );
}
```

It should log your data properly.

**Note**: You don't need state, actually. It's a better approach to manipulate over props, instead of saving data from props into state (in most cases).