# Can i import state values from one Component to another component in react-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This a Bala, new to React-Redux platform. And currently i have been working on the Todo App using React-redux. But unfortunately i am unable to go ahead from one issue. This is i have to use a values generated in one state component into to the another state component. Is it possible? or else can i import values fro redux-store?

Comment: Since you are using redux, you can handle all the communication between components using it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding React-Redux and mapStateToProps()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops)

Answer (score 1):

You can indirectly do this by using React-Redux store. You should maintain a common State inorder to do so. You just have to change the state as props and pass it to other component. `mapStateToProps` is used for this conversion.

eg.

```
 const mapStateToProps=state=>{
 return {...state};
 }
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

In your store have a state and maintain it globally.