# What is the purpose of mapStateToProps when State is already globally available?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is sort of a general theory question.

What is the purpose of using mapStateToProps to select a specific set of data from the Store and send it into the component as a Prop, when all of that data is already globally available to all components in the store?

Another way to phrase it would be, why am I going through the extra step of mapping state to props so that I can access the data with `props.something` when I could just access it with `state.something`?

Comment: _"when all of that data is already globally available to all components in the store?"_ - How is all the data already available to all the components? Components have access to only that data in the redux store that is passed to them as props.

Comment: I believe that it must be based on the following. Inside of a component if I am creating my map state to props function like so `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { streams: Object.values(state.streams) };
};` I am taking in state as an argument there... which means it is available there? Although I guess that this is a callback function, so when it gets executed in the store it is actually available there, and not here in the component... I may have just answered my own question.

Comment: If I console log `state.streams` I am told that it is undefined so state would actually be undefined within the scope of this component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding React-Redux and mapStateToProps()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202572/understanding-react-redux-and-mapstatetoprops)

Answer (score 1):

Components do not have access to all the data in the `redux` store. They only have access to that data in the `redux` store that is passed to them as `props`.

As far as your question of what's the purpose of `mapStateToProps`, is concerned, following are the main uses of `mapStateToProps`:

- Tell `react-redux` what data any particular component needs.
- Transform the store state and pass the transformed state to the component as a prop
- Help `react-redux` decide whether a particular component should re-render as a result of store update.

#### Tell React-Redux what data component needs

`mapStateToProps` function tells `react-redux` what data a particular component needs from the `redux` store. This function gets the whole state as an argument but the problem is that you can't access this inside the `React` component. It is passed to `mapStateToProps` function, not to your component. So you need `react-redux` to pass the required data to your component as `props`.

#### Transforming Store State

`.mapStateToProps` function can also be used to transform the store state in such a way that is appropriate for any particular component, for example:

- Combining different pieces of state from different parts of the store.
- Passing a data as a specific prop name
- Transforming data in any way that is appropriate for use by the component.

#### Help React-Redux decide whether a particular component should be re-rendered

Now you might ask, what if i tell `react-redux` to pass whole `state` argument to my component as a `prop`?

Problem with doing this is that whenever the state in the `redux` store updates, your component will re-render even if it didn't use any part of the state that changed.

This behavior is caused by how `react-redux` uses `mapStateToProps` function to decide whether a component should be re-rendered as a result of store's state update.

Whenever `redux` store updates, `react-redux` does a shallow comparison (`===`) of each field of the object returned by `mapStateToProps` function and if any of the field is different, your component will be re-rendered.

To prevent this behavior, you use `mapStateToProps` function to only get that data that is actually used inside the component. This way, if any un-related data is updated in the `redux` store, it won't cause a re-render of your component.

For more details of `mapStateToProps` function, see:

[`React Redux: Extracting Data with mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops)

Comment: That is the answer right there, this prevents your component from re-rendering if an unrelated piece of state gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the reason that the data is present in Redux Store.So to access that data we have to pass this HOC (Higher Order Component) mapStateToProps and wrap it around our component like for example TodoList in our case

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)
```

- So to access store's state data we have to first get it through props.
- In short the data present inside Store has been accessed inside a component through props and not with a state.Since the State is native to the Store and not the component where we are using it.